# Spring Boot define multiple exchanges

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I need to declare multiple Fanout exchanges

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  @Bean
  FanoutExchange exchange1() {
    return new FanoutExchange(exchangeName1, true, false);
  }

  @Bean
  FanoutExchange exchange2() {
    return new FanoutExchange(exchangeName2, true, false);
  }

  ....
  ....
}
```

As soon as I add the code for the `exchange2` I get the error:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of method binding in com.Application required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>     - exchange1: defined by method 'exchange1' in com.Application
>     - exchange2: defined by method 'exchange2' in com.Application
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you the solution:

1. user Qualifier on your bean
2. define which one from the 2 beans is the primary one using @Primary

Your code should look like

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("exchange1")
    @Primary
    FanoutExchange exchange1() {
       return new FanoutExchange(exchangeName1, true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("exchange2")
    FanoutExchange exchange2() {
       return new FanoutExchange(exchangeName2, true, false);
    }
 }
```